# Delete repeated vowels in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
def del_rep_vow(s):
    '''
    >>> del_rep_vow('adaptation')
    'adpttion'
    >>> del_rep_vow('repetitions')
    'reptitons'
    >>> del_rep_vow('kingkong')
    'kingkong'
    >>> del_rep_vow('aeiouaeiou')
    'aeiou'
    '''
    final_list = []
    for i in s:
        if i not in final_list:
            final_list.append(i)
    return ''.join(final_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

I don't know how to make the restriction that only repeated vowels have to be deleted once they are in the list. Any help will be very welcome.

Output of 'adaptation' must be 'adpttion', for example.

Comment: If a vowel is repeated, do you want to delete all occurrences or just the repeated occurrences?

Comment: just the repeated ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should maintain a Python set of vowel characters already seen.  For each new encountered letter as you walk down the string, only append a vowel if it is *not* in the set.

```py
def del_rep_vow(s):
    vowels_seen = set()
    final_list = []
    for i in s:
        if i in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
            if i not in vowels_seen:
                final_list.append(i)
                vowels_seen.add(i)
        else:
            final_list.append(i)

    return ''.join(final_list)

print(del_rep_vow('adaptation'))  # 'adpttion'
print(del_rep_vow('repetitions')) # 'reptitons'
print(del_rep_vow('kingkong'))    # 'kingkong'
print(del_rep_vow('aeiouaeiou'))  # 'aeiou'
```

Comment: @DanielHao: That will recreate the `set` on each test, it's a bad idea, and while I won't say it couldn't improve speed (the bulk reconstruction of the `set` might go faster than expected), it's wasteful. Using a `set` literal might provide some tiny benefit, e.g. `if i in {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}:` (on Python 3, the optimizer replaces that with a preconstructed `frozenset` literal so it isn't rebuilt each time), but frankly, given it's a guaranteed single character, and there's not many letters to test against, `if i in 'aeiou':` is probably as fast, if not faster (you're welcome to test).

Answer (score 2):

I feel this is pretty concise:

```
def del_rep_vow(s):
    for ch in 'eaiou':
        if ch in s:
            i = s.index(ch) + 1
            s = s[:i] + s[i:].replace(ch, '')
    return s


print(del_rep_vow('adaptation'))
print(del_rep_vow('repetitions'))
print(del_rep_vow('kingkong'))
print(del_rep_vow('aeiouaeiou'))
```

Result:

```
adpttion
reptitons
kingkong
aeiou
```

Comment: oh thanks, prettier than mine. I'll use it too

Comment: Did you nano-optimize the order for letter frequencies in English, or is it a typo?

Comment: I suppose I unconsciously nano-optimised :D - it feels like the right order to me, but I didn't give it much thought. But you're right, it is the right order to minimise the number of replacements (in English). However, if performance is a concern, user @TimBiegeleisen's solution would be more efficient. I just posted mine because I feel it's easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

The [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) method closely matches your need. It splits the string at the first occurrence of a separator and returns a 3-tuple containing the part before the separator, the separator itself or `""` if not found, and the part after the separator. All that remains is to remove the vowel from the after-part.

```
def del_rep_vow(s):
    for v in 'aeiou':
        before, vowel, after = s.partition(v)
        s = before + vowel + after.replace(v, '')
    return s

print(del_rep_vow('adaptation'))  # 'adpttion'
print(del_rep_vow('repetitions')) # 'reptitons'
print(del_rep_vow('kingkong'))    # 'kingkong'
print(del_rep_vow('aeiouaeiou'))  # 'aeiou'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also keep your initial code, adding just a little condition to the test:

```
def del_rep_vow(s):
    final_list = []
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    for i in s:
        if i not in vowels or i not in final_list: # allowed consonants to be added every time
            final_list.append(i)
    return ''.join(final_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

recursive solution:

```
def del_rep_vow(s):
    return del_rep_vow(s[:-1]) + ('' if s[-1] in 'aeiou' and s[-1] in s[:-1] else s[-1]) if s else ''

del_rep_vow('repetitions')  # reptitons'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain 2 lists of letters: one for the vowels you have seen so far, and other for the remaining letters in the string.

```
vowels = []
remaining = []
for c in s:
    if c in 'aeiou':
        if c in vowels:
            continue
        vowels.append(c)
    remaining.append(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach

```
def del_repts(x):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    foundVowels = ''
    rslt = ''
    for c in x:
        if c in vowels:
            if c not in foundVowels:
                rslt += c
                foundVowels += c
        else:
            rslt += c
    return rslt  

inl = ['adaptation', 'repetitions', 'kingkong', 'aeiouaeiou']
for itm in inl:
    print(f'{itm}\t->\t{del_repts(itm)}' )
```

Yields:

```
adaptation  ->  adpttion
repetitions ->  reptitons
kingkong    ->  kingkong
aeiouaeiou  ->  aeiou
```